# How can I make the custom button and ribbon I created in C# for a VSTO application visible in Outlook (MS Office 365 ProPlus)?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Using C#, I created a VSTO application for Outlook in MS Office 365 ProPlus. I have a custom button and ribbon, which I would like to have displayed in my Outlook ribbon. The code I created does everything I wrote in the logic, except it does not display.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;

namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {

        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            //  ThisAddIn mainapp = new ThisAddIn();
            if (((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello from the buttom");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello from the else");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amber,
Can you please tell what you did and share the piece of code that you expect to be working, but it doesn't?

Comment: Hello Gabriel,I added the code above for what I have in the ribbon, which is something simple - a pop-up window. But what I need is for the ribbon and button to be visible in Outlook 365.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? The code works fine, I just can't see the ribbon in Outlook.